# Why am I receiving a Pylance Error when Importing a Module, almost as if the Module is not being recognized?

Tags: python, import, module

I have a function (testfunc.py) in the same folder as my main script (_test_.py). When trying to import testfunc into _test_ I receive a Pylance Error.

[image]

See below scripts:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you show the error? It's hard to guess what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pylance has a different import resolution system than Jedi. It considers your workspace root and won't consider any other directory root unless you specify, it should show a relative import error.

Try adding this to your workspace settings.json file

```json
"python.analysis.extraPaths": ["StackOverflow/"]
}
```

The devs don't consider it a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/236) so you'd have to set separate roots every time.